# Heroku Postgres database push freezes

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I have a local Postgres database associated with an app on my local machine, and I would like to copy that database to the Heroku deployment of the app.

I tried:

```
heroku pg:push localdatabasename DATABASE_URL --app my-appname-23895
```

Here, I'm actually using the words `DATABASE_URL`, because listing my environment variables via `heroku config` shows that this is the name of the variable holding the database url, and not a color identifier like `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW`.

Heroku responds with:

```
heroku-cli: Pushing localdatabasename ---> postgresql-identifier-83435
```

and then freezes there without returning to the bash prompt.  If I open another bash window and log into Heroku Postgres with `heroku pg:psql`, then when I examine the table structure with `\dt` I get:

```
Did not find any relations.
```

Then when I go back to the bash window where I'm running `heroku pg:push`, I press Ctrl+C to quit, and then I get the error message:

```
pg_dump errored with 3221225786
```

or

```
pg_restore errored with 3221225786
```

Not sure if the appearance of both `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` means it's just extremely slow to push the database and I should just keep waiting for a longer time for `heroku pg:push` to finish, or if there's a problem with the push process.  I've had it running for over 3 hours with no apparent change.

I also tried:

```
PGUSER=username PGPWD=password heroku pg:push localdatabasename DATABASE_URL --app my-appname-23895
```

and got the same results.

Comment: How did you fix this? I am having the exact same problem?

Comment: @pauzca see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `pg:push`, I used `pg:dump` followed by `heroku pg:backups:restore`, per the solution described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export).

Comment: It worked at the end following that info.! But it's kind of a pain to have to upload the database to S3. I tried ways to upload it from my local, but it never worked. :(